# HAproxy statistics returned by querying UNIX socket

Tags: haproxy

can someone explain to me a bit the HAproxy stats as returned by querying stats socket ?
When I un the "show stats" against the socket I get the following returned:

```
application,FRONTEND,,,0,10,2000,48474,4548322,21176388,0,0,147,,,,,OPEN,,,,,,,,,1,1,0,,,,0,0,0,8,,,,0,23,48166,281,4,0,,0,8,48474,,,
application,app01,0,0,0,10,100,48325,4547948,21148475,,0,,0,2,0,0,UP,1,1,0,6,3,2910138,166,,1,1,1,,48325,,2,0,,8,L4OK,,0,0,23,48166,134,0,0,0,,,,2,0,
application,BACKEND,0,0,0,10,2000,48327,4548322,21176388,0,0,,2,2,0,0,UP,1,1,0,,3,2910138,166,,1,1,0,,48325,,1,0,,8,,,,0,23,48166,134,4,0,,,,,2,0,
```

I understand that FRONTEND bit keeps the stats about all incoming HTTP requests but what I don't quite get is what is the difference between 2nd and 3rd line ? app01 is a backend server where we are proxying HTTP requests to however HAproxy returns another extra line with svname set to BACKEND. I can see the output differs a bit between 2nd and 3rd line.
If anyone could shed a light on this it would be greatly appreciated. I need to collect some stats and would want to avoid the situation of missin some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BACKEND` line has the stats for the entire pool, the `app01` line the stats for that poolmember.

Comment: thanks for the answer - I was suspecting that...interesting thing is that there is only 1 and only server in the backend pool and that is app01 - why would the numbers differ in this case ?